# How to transform a recursive function to an iterative one

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to convert this recursive function to an iterative one using a stack:

```
void GetToTownRecursive(int x, Country &country, AList *accessiblesGroup, vector<eTownColor> &cities_colors)
{

    cities_colors[x - 1] = eTownColor::BLACK;
    accessiblesGroup->Insert(x);

    List *connected_cities = country.GetConnectedCities(x);
    if (!connected_cities->IsEmpty())
    {
        ListNode *curr_city = connected_cities->First();
        while (curr_city != nullptr)
        {
    
            if (cities_colors[curr_city->GetTown() - 1] == eTownColor::WHITE)
            {
                GetToTownRecursive(curr_city->GetTown(), country, accessiblesGroup, cities_colors);
            }
            curr_city = curr_city->GetNextNode();
        }
    }
}
```

The function takes a town number as an input and returns a list of towns that are connected to that town (directly as well as indirectly).

I'm having difficulty converting it because of the while loop within and because the only action taken after the recursive call is the promotion of the list iterator - `curr_city`. What should I push into the stack in this case?

Would be glad for your help!

Comment: Nested loop... Outer one replaces the recursive call and iterates as long as the stack is not empy (prefilled with very first city). Then take one city from stack, push all its children onto in reverse order (the inner/nested loop) and handle city just popped from stack.

Comment: There is no button somewhere that just needs to be pushed in order to convert any recursive function into an iterative one. This is done by analyzing the underlying recursive algorithm and defining a logically equivalent iterative one. In the case of tail recursion this is obvious. In this case, it's one. The shown code is, unfortunately, is woefully insufficient in explaining the algorithm. What is `county`? What is `First()`? What is `GetNextNode()`? Etc... Some reasonable guesses can be made, to assume what they are. But the only result of guesses are more guesses as to what the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action taken after the recursive call is the whole remainder of the while loop (all the remaining iterations).  On the stack, you have to save any variables that could change during the recursive call, but will be needed after.  In this case, that's just the value of `curr_city`.

If `goto` was still a thing, you could then replace the recursive call with:

1. save `curr_city`
2. set `x = curr_city->GetTown()`
3. goto start

Then at the end, you have to

4. check stack
5. If there's a saved `curr_city`, restore it and goto just after (3)

Because it's *not* acceptable to use gotos for this sort of thing (they make your code hard to understand), you have to break up your function into 3 top-level parts:

- part 1: all the stuff before the first recursive call, ending with 1-3
- part 2: a loop that does all the stuff between recursive calls, ending with 1-3 if it gets to another recursive call, or 4-5 if it doesn't.
- part 3: anything that happens after the *last* recursive call, which is nothing in this case.

Typically there is then a lot of cleanup and simplification you can do after this rearrangement.

Comment: Although I knew the approach you described, your explanation of how to apply it made it much clearer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be something like the following.

```
void GetToTown(int x, Country &country, AList *accessiblesGroup,
   vector<eTownColor> &cities_colors)
{
    Stack<int> pendingX = new ...
      
    pendingX.push(x);
    
    while (!pendingX.isEmpty()) {
        int localX = pendingX.Pop();
        cities_colors[localX - 1] = eTownColor::BLACK;
        accessiblesGroup->Insert(localX);
        
        List *connected_cities = country.GetConnectedCities(localX);
        if (!connected_cities->IsEmpty())
        {
            ListNode *curr_city = connected_cities->First();
            while (curr_city != nullptr)
            {            
                if (cities_colors[curr_city->GetTown() - 1] == nColor::WHITE)
                {
                    pendingX.Push(curr_city->GetTown());
                }
                curr_city = curr_city->GetNextNode();
            }
         }
    }
}
```